# issue with 'file browser dialog' when combining files

Tags: c#

Currently, I have a browser dialog that opens and allows the user to select a folder in which doc / docx files will be merged into one file. At the moment, it is rigged up to merge files once the 'DialogResult.ok' button is dismissed in the browser dialog. as shown below:

```
private void browseButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FolderBrowserDialog diagBrowser = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        diagBrowser.Description = "Select a folder which contains files needing combined...";

        // Default folder, altered when the user selects folder of choice 
        string selectedFolder = @"C:\";
        diagBrowser.SelectedPath = selectedFolder;

        // initial file path display
        folderPath.Text = diagBrowser.SelectedPath;

        if (DialogResult.OK == diagBrowser.ShowDialog())
        {
            // Grab the folder that was chosen
            selectedFolder = diagBrowser.SelectedPath;
            folderPath.Text = diagBrowser.SelectedPath;
    }

    private void combineButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

           string[] AllDocFolder = Directory.GetFiles(selectedFolder, "*.doc");
           string outputFileName = (@"C:\Test\Merge\Combined.docx");
           MsWord.Merge(AllDocFolder, outputFileName, true);

            // Message displaying how many files are combined. 
            MessageBox.Show("A total of " + AllDocFolder.Length.ToString() + " documents have been merged", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }

    }
```

the issue i am having is that i want the 'combineButton' to merge the documents as opposed to the 'DialogResult.ok'. When i copy the lines:

```
 string[] AllDocFolder = Directory.GetFiles(selectedFolder, "*.doc");
           string outputFileName = (@"C:\Test\Merge\Combined.docx");
           MsWord.Merge(AllDocFolder, outputFileName, true);
```

into the combineButton area, i get an error saying 'the name 'selectedFolder' does not exist in the current context'. This may be a stupid question, but is there a quick way to remedy this?

Comment: If you want to access a variable in two methods, create a private variable in the class.

Comment: @codecaster - the issue i am having is, the string 'selectedfolder' defaults as c:\\ however this changes once the user selects the folder they want to actually combine. i am trying to use a separate button to then take this updated filepath and merge its content, as opposed to the default c:\\ folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand your problem, you want to split the folder selection and the merging of the documents, right?

So you could put the information about the target directory into a class variable:

```
public class MyForm
{   
    private string[] _sourceFiles;

    private void browseButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FolderBrowserDialog diagBrowser = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        diagBrowser.Description = "Select a folder which contains files needing combined...";

        // Default folder, altered when the user selects folder of choice 
        string selectedFolder = @"C:\";
        diagBrowser.SelectedPath = selectedFolder;

        // initial file path display
        folderPath.Text = diagBrowser.SelectedPath;

        if (DialogResult.OK == diagBrowser.ShowDialog())
        {
            // Grab the folder that was chosen
            selectedFolder = diagBrowser.SelectedPath;
            folderPath.Text = diagBrowser.SelectedPath;

            _sourceFiles = Directory.GetFiles(selectedFolder, "*.doc");            
        }
    }

    private void combineButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_sourceFiles != null && _sourceFiles.Length > 0)
        {
            string outputFileName = (@"C:\Test\Merge\Combined.docx");
            MsWord.Merge(_sourceFiles, outputFileName, true);
            // Message displaying how many files are combined. 
            MessageBox.Show("A total of " + _sourceFiles.Length.ToString() + " documents have been merged", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the code worked perfectly, however i did have to make one change.

I had to change `documentFolder.Length.ToString()`

to `_sourceFiles.Length.ToString()`

as i was getting the same error as previously mentioned in the question. thank you for the help

Comment: @cgraham720 ah sorry, that was a copy&waste error, thanks for the info